# How to open files at last position in Textwrangler?

Tags: text-editor, bbedit

I am using Textwrangler (Version 4.5.3) to edit a set of files and I switch between them very often. 
Instead of opening all files separately I selected the whole folder containing them and opened this.

My problem now is:

Every time I switch from i.e. line 600  of file A  in folder XY to file B in folder XY/Z, and then back to file A I have to scroll back to line 600, as Textwrangler opens this file again at the first line.

What I want now is an option that makes it possible to let Textwrangler "remember" where I left off last time I had it open.

I looked through all preferences in TextWrangler but couldn't find an option that does what I want.

Comment: ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. No, unfortunately I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try a program called Brackets.  It does exactly what you want.  Its also a really cool looking editor, and only requires one window.

Link to Brackets by Adobe: [Here](http://brackets.io/)